# How to go through cells and group similar cells with borders

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using trying to use VBA to put borders around the groups of similar numbers in a report.

In the function I'm iterating through the values of column A to see if there are similar values to group. If they are found then they are added to a range via the union function. once they are all selected they should be formatted with a border around the lot. It seems to only ground the last cell row in each row.

```
Sub OrderFormatting()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Report")

    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim search As String
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim searchRange2 As Range
    Dim selectRange As Range
    Dim tempSelectRange As Range
    Dim activerow As Long

    Set searchRange = Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    Set searchRange2 = Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

    For Each cell2 In searchRange
    search = cell2.Text
    For Each cell In searchRange2
        activerow = cell.Row()
        If selectRange Is Nothing Then
             Set selectRange = Range("A2:H2")
             Set tempSelectRange = Range("A2:H2")
        ElseIf (cell.Text = search) Then
             Set tempSelectRange = ws.Range(Cells(activerow, 1), Cells(activerow, 8))
        Else
             Set selectRange = Union(selectRange, tempSelectRange)
        End If
    Next cell
        selectRange.BorderAround _
        ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThin
    Next cell2


End Sub
```

I expected all similar records in column A to be grouped by a border around the lot. The sheet will be sorted in descending order so they are all grouped with one another. For some reason it only applies the border to the final row (A:H) in the set.

Thanks, and sorry about the adhoc method. Im sure there is a much efficient way :)

Comment: A few notes: 1. You should declare `lastrow` as `Long` 2. You should declare `cell` and `cell2` as `Range`s 3. You don't need `searchRange` and `searchRange2`, you can simply loop through `searchRange` both times 4. No parentheses behind `Row`, it should be `activerow = cell.Row` 5. Use `.Value2` instead of `.Text` to extract cell values. 6. It might be worth it to look into [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to make this a bit easier.

Comment: I think the `If` inside the second loop, should be two separate statements. First you want to check if your Ranges are `Nothing`, if so set them to a certain range (please note, that you should reset the ranges for each `cell2`). Then you want to check if the cell you're looking at has your search text in it. So those should be separate statements, since the should both be able to be run during one iteration. To debug this more easily you could simply set the border of each range individually inside the `If` statement instead of doing it all at once at the end. So you can see what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code a bit to archieve what you wanted. I hope it is understandable.
Its not that pretty but it works.

```
Sub OrderFormatting()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Report")

    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim countMatches As Long
    Set searchRange = Range("A2:A" & lastrow + 1)
    Dim search As String

    For Each cell In searchRange
        If search = "" Then
            search = cell.Text
        ElseIf search = cell.Text Then
            countMatches = countMatches + 1
        Else
            countMatches = countMatches + 1
            Range("A" & cell.Row - countMatches & ":H" & cell.Row - 1).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThin
            countMatches = 0
            search = cell.Text
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate!, a lot less complex than mine.. and works :)